# Anchor TextView to bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'd like to have a `TextView` that stays at the bottom of the screen and the content above it will be scrollable but the bottom `TextView` does not move as the user scrolls.

This is what I have, so far:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:text="Unlock Pro Settings"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: but the bottom TextView does not move as the user scrolls. - means? whats happening as of now?

Comment: Please read your question first and edit it

Comment: Right now everything is scrolling.  I just want the "tv_content" `TextView` to scroll while the bottom `TextView` stays in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the bottom `TextView` out of the `NestedScrollView`, so that it won't scroll with the other `TextView`. So I exchanged the `ConstraintLayout` with the `NestedScrollView`, and added some padding to make the text clear on the screen.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="click me" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Unlock Pro Settings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: OK I screwed up my question.  I also need to add a button under the "tv_content" `TextView` and I'm getting an error that you can only have one direct child under a `ScrollView`

Comment: do you want the button to be scrollable with the `tv_content`?

Comment: This works great. I guess that was pretty simple but I was trying to avoid nested layouts because I thought one reason `ConstraintLayout` was created was to avoid nested layouts.